# Storing sequence Information in JSON

Tags: python, json, regex

I want to store some sequence information in a JSON. For example, I want to store a variable value which can have following values:

```
some_random_string_2
some_random_string_3
some_random_string_4
...
```

To do so, I have tried using the following format:

```
json_obj = {
    "k1": {
        "nk1": "some_random_string_{$1}"
        "patterns": {
            "p1": {
                "pattern": "[2-9]|[1-9]\d+",
                "symbol_type": "int",
                "start_symbol": 2,
                "step": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above json contains regex pattern for variable string, its type, start symbol and step. But, it seems unnecessarily complicated and difficult to generate sequence from.

Is there some simpler way to store this sequence information so that its easier to generate the sequence while parsing?

Currently, I don't have exhaustive patterns list, so we'll have to assume, that it can be anything that can be written as a regular exp. On a side note, I'll be using python to parse this json and generate a sequence.

Comment: Please rephrase your question whereas it is easily conspicious that  what you have- what you want and what you tried sofar.

Comment: ok i'll try to explain it better, but please let me know what part did you find difficult to understand, i've tried to state everything as clearly as possible, I want to store sequence information (numerical at first) in json, and generate sequence from that in python.

Comment: `following values (int val>2)` but your example includes `some_random_string_2`